# When I am giving this " ‘Winnie The Pooh’ " to variable, some external characters are coming like this \xe2\x80\x98

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I am giving this " ‘Winnie The Pooh’ " to variable, some external characters are coming like this  \xe2\x80\x98 and when I am populating this in my data symbols changes to "â€˜" , I want to show the symbols as they are.
I am using python 2.7

```
>>> a =  "‘Winnie The Pooh’"
>>> a
'\xe2\x80\x98Winnie The Pooh\xe2\x80\x99'
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: I think the problem is that ‘ is a non ascii character. You must encode it differently.

Comment: E2 80 98 is the UTF-8 encoding of [U+2018](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm). Apparently you have a curly quote, and a terminal which isn't properly configured for Unicode. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info

Comment: I am using python 2.7
>>> a =  "‘Winnie The Pooh’"
>>> a
'\xe2\x80\x98Winnie The Pooh\xe2\x80\x99'

Comment: Turn off smart quotes and stuff in your editor.

Comment: Why are you not using `unicode` literals?

Comment: It's working fine in python 3.4

Comment: yeah akash it is working in python 3.4, but i am using python 2.7